# Elixir Logger - How do You Modify the Contents of a Logged Message?

Tags: logging, elixir

Is there any way to hook into the Elixir Logger before messages get sent to the backends? I need to strip out potentially sensitive information before it gets written to external systems.

Comment: Take a look at this http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.0/logger/Logger.Translator.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for the sake of others who might come across this question and not notice the comment I posted, I believe you can accomplish what you're trying to achieve via the [Logger.Translator](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.0/logger/Logger.Translator.html) module. You would build a module and function to pattern match on the sensitive data that you want to filter and then add the module and function via the [Logger.add_translator/1](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.0/logger/Logger.html#add_translator/1) function.

---

EDIT: In response to the comment left by the poster of the original question: I suggest you look [here](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.0/logger/Logger.html) and look specifically at these two options: `:handle_otp_reports` and `:handle_sasl_reports`.  I'd also draw your attention to this passage in the documentation:

> Furthermore, Logger allows messages sent by Erlang’s error_logger to
>   be translated into an Elixir format via translators.

Assuming you're outputting the messages that you want to filter via Erlang's error_logger, this is the right approach.  If you're not outputting those messages via error_logger then please add more detail about the mechanism you're using to output the messages you want to scrub.

Comment: Unfortunately the translator module only seems to work for logs coming from Erlang. Not Elixir logging.